# Flask Debugger Mode: Setting up Variables

Tags: python, flask

I'm learning Flask and I want to create a small-scale application using this framework. However, the debug mode doesn't allow me to view changed content upon reload. Reloading the webpage doesn't help (I have to turn the server off and on every time I want to see changes). Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you

i) app.py

```
from flask import Flask

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "<p>Change</p>"
```

ii) cmd prompt

```
set FLASK_APP=app.py
set FLASK_ENV=development
set FLASK_DEBUG=1
```

Comment: Please post your code and output as code-formatted text. Screenshots of code can not be accepted on Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Klaus D. I have made the necessary edits

Comment: Had you tried `if __name__=="__main__":
 app.run(debug=1)`? And please mention exact error/problem in question... I am not able to exactly know what is your issue.

Comment: @Xitiz I've tried using `if __name__=="__main__":  app.run(debug=1)`  . Still coming up with the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

For windows, try using a `.env` file i.e:
Create a file called `.env` in your project folder, then add the values i.e

```
FLASK_APP=app.py
FLASK_ENV=development
FLASK_DEBUG=1
```

Then modify your code to look like this:

```
from flask import Flask
from dotenv import load_dotenv

load_dotenv()

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/")
def hello_world():
    return "<p>Change</p>"
```

Then install the dotenv module:

```
pip install python-dotenv
```

Then run your application.

Comment: Still facing the same problems

Answer (score 1):

Try using export instead of set i.e

```bash
export FLASK_APP=app.py
export FLASK_ENV=development
export FLASK_DEBUG=1
```

Comment: I'm on a windows platform, export isn't recognized on CMD afaik?